# How to update distribution data

Tags: updates, release-management

I have a machine that's been through many updates of Ubuntu and recently Xubuntu, but now seems stuck and some things won't update, like the graphical card drivers, so I get no pictures on the console, and cannot control the machine locally.  I have to boot it up, and log in from another machine via SSH.

When I login with SSH, I'm greeted with this message:

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.16.11-76051611-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

0 updates can be applied immediately.


37 updates could not be installed automatically. For more details,
see /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log
Last login: Sun Apr 24 19:01:08 2022 from 10.53.90.92
```

When I explore the log, I see repetitions of the message

```
2022-03-01 02:23:17,542 WARNING Could not figure out development release: Distribution data outdated. Please check for an update for distro-info-data. See /usr/share/doc/distro-info-data/README.Debian for details.
```

And when I look in `/usr/share/doc/distro-info-data/README.Debian`, it tells me to look for updated info, commenting that...

```
On Ubuntu, it is:
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $RELEASE-updates main
where $RELEASE is the name of your release.
```

And here I'm stuck, because I don't know what to do with that leading "deb".  It's not a command, so perhaps it wants to be in a file somewhere.  I point a browser at the URL and I see a directory structure that looks vaguely familiar but no instructions about how to use it.

In response to a comment (and thanks for the editing tip) here's the contents of /etc/apt/sources.list

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170215.2)]/ xenial main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner

# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main universe multiverse restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security universe main multiverse restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe main multiverse restricted
```

And I see that I almost have the indicated deb line in the file, but I'm not sure if almost is good enough; what's the effect of having "universe" in there?

How do I get this machine back on track?

Comment: At some point in time, it is advised to start again from scratch and perform a fresh install: a big spring cleanup.

Comment: Can you post the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list`? For formatting, please use [code fences](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code)

Comment: @Nmath contents posted above

Comment: Even though they aren't enabled, your sources list is filled with xenial sources from 16.04. Those shouldn't be there. This suggests to me that we're just scratching the surface of potentially many problems. I agree that it's probably time for a new/clean installation. If your sources list is still showing sources from a 6 year old release, that's not a good indicator.

Comment: @Nmath I am guessing that they were commented-out and superceded by a release-upgrade operation.  I'm also guessing it's normal because they are present in other hosts here (like the one I'm typing on) that are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I got an answer from a support channel.  I wasn't expecting that because
the machine is out of warranty, but they gave me these commands, and they worked.  When I rebooted I was greeted by a cat (in the wallpaper) that I
had not seen in weeks.

The bit about the desktop is there because they had some concerns about the logs they saw.  And the video card is not supported by the newest drivers, so an older one is pulled down.

Anyway: the commands:

```
sudo apt purge ~nnvidia

sudo apt clean  

sudo apt update -m  

sudo dpkg --configure -a  

sudo apt install -f  

sudo apt full-upgrade  

sudo apt autoremove --purge

sudo apt install --reinstall lightdm xubuntu-desktop

sudo apt install nvidia-driver-470
```